# mandatory one way operation for duplex service

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it mandatory for all methods inside the duplex service interface to be one-way ?

Can the interface not contain methods both one way and request reply pattern at the same time ?

Asking because the example demonstrate a scenario for one-way function only.

Answer (score 0):

Methods within a duplex service are usually one-way, but not required, meaning that only a request is sent and no response is returned or expected. In addition, in the duplex service, the server can initiate communication with the client.

An interface may not contain both one-way and request-reply patterns. You can read [this article](https://derekwill.com/2015/05/11/building-duplex-services-with-wcf/) for more details.

Comment: So it means that it is customary to have separate service interface and service host for request-reply and duplex pattern respectively.

Comment: A separate interface seems more practical and concise.